# By clicking on my app's launcher icon, bring my app to foreground and not launch new Activity

Tags: android

My app has 2 activities - A and B. From homescreen I launch A, from A I launch B. The activity stack looks like this: A-B. Now I press HOME button, and from homescreen click again on my app icon, which launches A and adds it on top of the activity stack, which now looks like this: A-B-A. But I just want to bring my application to foreground, is that possible in Android?

P.S. My other app works as I want, what can be the problem?

Comment: hi I am experiencing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you configure your intent-filter like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I have exactly this intent filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `android:launchMode` of your Activity in your Manifest.xml.

See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Agreed, this gives you an option for SingleInstance and SingleTask. SingleTask looks like it will only allow one instance of an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing [this nasty Android bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265). See my answer for how to get around it.

And yes, it still exists, even in Android 5 :-(