# Android Application: Returning to the activity where you stopped

Tags: android-activity, android-manifest

I've been making a simple android app here, but i'm stuck with a problem. The app is composed of 1 splash(that is the main activity) and 4 other activities(one of them is used to go to the other 3). Whenever i exit my application and resume it with the process manager, it opens the activity i stopped at. But, when i resume it by clicking on the icon, it goes back to the splash activity. **Is there any way to make it always go to where i stopped? Any flag or something i can set on the manifest?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Android bug. The standard behaviour is to return to your application (in the same state as when you left) when launching it from the HOME screen. However, if you started your application **for the first time** from the installer, this gets broken.

To check if you are seeing this behaviour, go to the Settings->Applications and force close your application. Now go to the HOME screen and start your application. Use your application for a bit. Now press the HOME button to return to the HOME screen and launch your application again by clicking on the icon. It should return to your application exactly the way you left it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265 for more information and other links to this long-standing and nasty Android bug.