# How to return to already running Android activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am working on a fitness app which has a home activity which launches a workouts activity which launches a specific workout activity.  In the workout activity, one may start a workout.  Thereafter, one might want to then press the Home button and launch a music player or perhaps the web browser.  At some point, one would probably launch the app again to return to the already running workout, but that ends up launching a new instance of the app.  When I set the `launchMode` on the home activity to `singleTask`, it simply goes back to the existing home activity when I tap the launcher icon.  What I would like is for it to go back to the workout in progress, which is where you would depart the app.

Essentially, I'm looking for behavior identical to iOS where it would simply restore the app to its current state if you "relaunched" the app and it was still running.

Comment: if the user wants to continue where they left off they should use the recents apps button and if the app is still in memory it will return you to what you were doing

Comment: I believe you'd have to serialize the state. Android determines when to destroy your app. Or at least that's the way I've done it.

Comment: @tyczj That's how I (the developer) get back to it, but try explaining that to Joe User. :-)

Comment: you simply tell them that this is what the recents app list is for and your problem is solved. you cannot change how android does its memory management and your users need to understand that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supposed to work as you've described. In most cases, it actually does work like that. However, there is a long-standing nasty Android bug which causes the behaviour you've described. This happens when you launch the app for the first time from an IDE (like Eclipse) or by clicking the "open" button on the Installer screen. To see if this is what you're seeing, just do this:

1. Go to Settings->Applications, choose your app and click "Force close"
2. Launch your app, do something, press the HOME button
3. Launch your app again.

You should return to where you left off. If not, something else bad is going on. If that is the case, please post your manifest in your question, because the problem is likely in these.

Don't try to use special `launchMode`s to fix this. This just creates more problems.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265) for more information about the nasty long-standing Android bug.

Comment: Thanks David.  I'll check and get back to you.  However, this issue is being reported from the field where the app is installed via TestFlight.

Comment: Well, the bug I mentioned is present on all devices (that I know of), so you may be able to reproduce this problem yourself by installing your app, opening it from the installer screen, do something, press HOME, then launch your app again by selecting the icon from the list of installed applications.