# Android back stack after activity backgrounded

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having a problem where the back stack is lost after you background an activity.  I am already using "android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" but that doesn't seem to fix my problem.

MainActivity->SomeActivity.

Send SomeActivity to background.
Select SomeActivity from window list.

Back button does not go to MainActivity.  It goes to the home screen.

How do I make it go back to MainActivity?

```
Intent i = new Intent(self, SomeActivity.class);
i.putExtra("launch", 1);
startActivity(i);
```

It will go back to MainActivity if the application is never background-ed.

Comment: Are you calling finish() on MainActivity when you are starting SomeActivity? How does your mainifest look like? And pls paste the intent you are using to start the SomeActivity.

Comment: Updated Original Post.  No, I am not calling finish() on MainActivity.

Comment: @misterbiscuit You should share some code in SomeActivity too, and how can you send SomeActivity to background? by press Home button?

Comment: @R4j yeah.  Home button.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19791634/719212 I had faced with this problem before.

Comment: I am not closing the MainActivity however.  I just setup a test app and it works properly there.  Eventually I will figure out what is causing it and post.

Comment: Worse than I thought.  MainActivity is leaking because it is never destroyed in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Is the root of the problem.  While the back button does work if you never press the HOME button; the back stack will be cleared when the singleInstance activity is restarted.

Comment: then should I use the singleInstance flag on MainActivity?