# how to turn back to same activity instance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I have made a Mediaplayer (just play songs from SD card) and it is not a service but a single activity.  by pressing the home button the player continues playing in the back ground.
now my problem is how to get back to the same instance of the activity by launching the application. mine starts a new activity while the previous instance of mediaplayer is still playing the song.
I have seen many similar questions but mostly was about the services specially in mediaplayer cases.
is it possible to set some flags onDestroy and check them again onCreate or somthing similar ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

> mine starts a new activity while the previous instance of mediaplayer is still playing the song

Yes, this is a behavior, on start - new Activity has been created.

> I have seen many similar questions but mostly was about the services

There is no way, run Player in Service in order to bind new created Activity with the Player

Comment: well I will try so , I thought maybe by Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT could do something

Comment: @AmirHM `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT` is not a flag that you should set in an `Intent`. This flag is set in the `Intent` by Android in certain cases. This won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the launch mode - single instance, for your activity.

android:launchMode=[ "singleInstance"]

in your Media Player activity in Android Manifest.xml file. It might work.

Comment: I have tried that , it helps if pressing home button , but if with back button you exit the activity onDestroy() is called and the instance is removed from stack, so in return another instance is created

Comment: If you click on Android Device back button, default implementation is Activity OnDestroy method is called and activity gets destroyed. But we can overwrite the device back button and that way, you can avoid calling onDestroy method.

Answer (score 0):

If you press HOME to put the application in the background, and then launching the application creates a new Activity, you are probably seeing this long-standing nasty Android bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265

To check if you are seeing this bug, just force close your application, then launch from the HOME screen, start playing sound, press HOME button, then launch application again from HOME screen. It shouldn't create a new instance of your activity.

Pleae don't set `launchMode="singleInstance"`. This is not necessary and will create more problems than it will solve.

Comment: yes thanks I got it , well any way I have changed the whole program and used service , though it took 2 days but was good experience, and now am working on TelephonyManager and PhoneStateListener for pause in the case of income call.