# 'startactivity called from non-activity context service' warning when launching intent from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, service, notifications, android-pendingintent

I've a `service` which starts a `notification` with `startForeground()`, I want the notification to launch an activity on click.
The `acitivty` I want to launch defined as `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and usually runs before the service starts.
Here is my `pending intent` creation code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

When I click on the notification I get the following warning :

```
startActivity called from non-Activity context; 
forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent........
```

I've also tried getting the activity with `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` but got the same warning.
How should I make this right ?

Comment: This makes no sense. The code you have is absolutely fine and should NOT produce the error messages you see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` for `PendingIntent.getActivity`. Better use `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`.

And try to use `Context` of `Activity` instead `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Use the `activity context` even if I call from a `service` ? Should I save the service `activity` creator context for that ?

Comment: Try to fix FLAG_ONE_SHOT first.

Comment: I did, it works fine. Thanks. But what about the incorrect context ?

Comment: It determine how you use this Service. 

They are both instances of Context, but the application instance is tied to the lifecycle of the application, while the Activity instance is tied to the lifecycle of an Activity. Thus, they have access to different information about the application environment.

Comment: The service should live as long as the application lives, when the service dies, so is the application, meaning, the activity will not be active unless the service is. So I should I get an activity context to move to the new activity ?

Comment: In this better case use application context.

Comment: If you are using `PendingIntent.getActivity()`, and you use this `PendingIntent` in a `Service`, or put it in a `Notification`, you MUST set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. If you don't, Android will issue a warning and set the flag for you, but that i just Android being nice.

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference which `Context` you use when you call the `Intent` constructor like this: `new Intent(Context, Activity.class)`. The `Context` in this case **is only used to get the package name of the component**.

Comment: What is **FLAG_ONE_SHOT**?