# Home view is returned if I restore my app from apps icon android apk

Tags: android, apk, restore, homescreen

When I run my apk directly in device without connecting the app to eclipse, and when I minimize my app such as pressing the home button -
if I press my app icon from opened app it will open the latest opened activity.

But if I press the icon of the app from app, the app run from the home activity.

I don't know the cause knowing that I don't override onpause or onstop or ondestroy method.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I think this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode can point you in good direction

Comment: You are probably seeing this Android bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265