# Android app starts fresh after intent action

Tags: android, android-intent

I am launching skype with the below code from a button click.

```
Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(uri.toString());
Intent myIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED", skypeUri);
myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
appContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```

It gets launched as a seperate activity and my app goes in background. When call is done, and i click on my app from background running apps, it starts from first screen however the call was placed from third screen. Any idea where I am wrong in implementation.

I want my app to go to background as soon as call button is clicked. When i am done with skype call and starts it again from background running apps it should not start from first screen. It should start from that 3rd screen only where i left it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you launched your app directly after installation (or from an IDE like AndroidStudio or Eclipse)? Maybe you are seeing this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283079/re-launch-of-activity-on-home-button-but-only-the-first-time

Comment: Maybe system kills your app process during the call. Hard to say. What is appContext? Where do you have this code? Activity? Fragment?