# Exact activity sequence in app (Android history stack)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

And again about Android activities back stack magic. So I have two activities A→B (playlist A and player B), and I want the app should always close when Back pressed in A. But it doesn't.

Both activities launches as `singleTop`, B also has `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` and defined A as parent. B goes back to A with following flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Everything works fine except the next case: 
**A→B**, 
Home pressed, 
Launch app again from desk and got **A** opened, 
Press Back button, 
Here app should be closed but **B** shown again.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `and I want the app should always close when Back pressed in A. But it doesn't` When you press back and activity A is your root activity declared with launcher and inten action.main for example, and you are at activity A at the moment you press back. Then you will come back to the homescreen.. `Press Back button, Here app should be closed but B shown again.` i don't get that you want to launch directly to activity B and close A ? What do you mean with close..finish() or completely killin the task?

Comment: @Mike I want A goes to homescreen by Back pressed, but B opened (kept in stack)

Comment: Did you originally launch the app from the HOME screen? or from an IDE (Eclipse, etc.) or the installer? You may be seeing this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK , it means a new instance of the activity is launched. You may have to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag with single task option in manifest.