# Back without destroying an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have A and B activities. A is `singleTop` on launch, B is `excludeFromRecents`. When I back from B to A, B is always destroying. How to prevent it? When I press Home then B is just stopped and not destoying. Thanks.

Following back code if B activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityPlaylist.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Without flags back not working at all.

I also have prevention of creating new instance in `onCreate` of A reason of I launch app from Eclipse ([bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265)):

```
    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        // Android launched another instance of the root activity into an existing task
        //  so just quietly finish and go away, dropping the user back into the activity
        //  at the top of the stack (ie: the last state of this task)
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

Upd: my case is I need do not lose B condition, including list position and so on.

Comment: Just to check, can you achieve what you want to do by saving relevant data and then reopening it when the activity is called again. Just a quick suggestion...

Comment: Can you explain your use case?  I'm not aware of a way to accomplish this specifically.

Comment: @csmurphy84 I need play some animation when I back to B. Of course I can save and restore activity data, but just not destroying it is a simpler way to do that guess. Besides B not destroying by Home pressed.

Comment: Setting B as `singleTop` takes no effect

Comment: You have to override onBackPressed()

Comment: The first snippet placed in `onBackPressed`