# Android app not on relaunch from background not maintaing state

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activity in my application. I intent from A to B and then put my application in background but when i relaunch the application it starts form Activity A not maintains it state of Activity B.

Activity A & Activity B declaration in android manifest :

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:label="vishal"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" />
<activity
            android:name="ActivityB"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:label="vishal"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" />
```

I havent used any flags. I have used startActivityForResults().

Comment: Can you show how you've declared the activity B in the manifest also how are you starting the activity B ( i.e using which flags) ?

Comment: What you are seeing is not standard behaviour. You may be seeing this nasty Android bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265 To test that theory, please force stop your app, then start it from the list of available applications and see if the problem is still there.