# Having <activity-alias> breaks a contract of singleTop mode

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Here's the problem. I have an <activity-alias> in my manifest defined as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name=".HomeActivity"/>

<activity-alias
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:targetActivity=".HomeActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

Now, user starts `MainActivity` using a launcher icon, it forwards to the `HomeActivity`.

I also have an Intent to start `HomeActivity` from the navigation drawer. It is started with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flags - to reuse existing instance of activity.

The problem is that this does not work as intended and it actually creates a new instance of `HomeActivity` (even though it is currently on top and visible!).
This happens because an activity backstack contains an entry for `.MainActivity`, not the `HomeActivity` it forwarded to in the end.

**Question:** I suspect this might or might not be the bug in Android, but I have a difficult time of figuring out a decent workaround.  Asking for help here! :)

I need only single activity started, and when user selects an item in navdrawer, that single activity should get onNewIntent(), not the new activity spawning!

Getting rid of an activity-alias fixes things, but this is not an acceptable option for me...

Here's the `adb dumpsys` result after the activity is started from launcher and then user selects 'Home' in navdrawer which starts activity directly, not through the alias (this dump confirms that there are two entries with different names):

```
  Main stack:
    TaskRecord{4181c408 #61 A ru.treto.tile U 0}
    Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=ru.treto.tile/.HomeActivity }
      Hist #2: ActivityRecord{412514b8 ru.treto.tile/.HomeActivity}
        Intent { flg=0x24000000 cmp=ru.treto.tile/.HomeActivity }
        ProcessRecord{412b06e0 10165:ru.treto.tile/u0a63}
      Hist #1: ActivityRecord{41723200 ru.treto.tile/.MainActivity}
        Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=ru.treto.tile/.MainActivity }
        ProcessRecord{412b06e0 10165:ru.treto.tile/u0a63}
```

Comment: You may be seeing this nasty Android bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265 To check if that is happening, force close your app and then start it from the HOME screen or list of available applications (do NOT launch it from the installer or via IDE).

Comment: Otherwise, please explain hy you need the alias, maybe there's another way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: @DavidWasser nope, that's not it. No downloads are taking place and it happens on *any* start. I need an activity alias because I accidentaly changed the main activity's name and this leads to removal of an app icon from user's home screen. The company I work for insisted that this needs to be fixed, and having an alias with an old class name is the way I can keep changing main activity name. I guess I'll have to rename it back, because I see no solution to this at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of referencing your `HomeActivity` in the classes that are launching it, you'll need to alter those intents to start "`MainActivity`" instead.

EX:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(mContext, "ru.treto.tile.MainActivity");
```

Alternately, if you're using another `IntentFilter` scheme, you can move those IntentFilter elements to your `alias` entry in the manifest:

```
<activity-alias 
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:target="ru.treto.tile.HomeActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ru.treto.tile.ACTION_OF_AWESOME" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

Comment: Marking as correct, but I haven't checked if it works and my code changed to much to do that now, let's hope you are right :) Thanks.

Comment: @dimsuz Fair enough :) We found your question because we were having the same problem and this is the workaround I came up with.  the explicit classname reference works; the intent filter bit is untested but I assume that it works since it works for `LAUNCHER`

Comment: I had the same problem, and this solved it.  It seems that the alias name rather than the target name is what goes on the back stack.  Up-voted.  Thank you!

Comment: I dont get how this solves anything, the whole point of those aliases is that you can have multiple different aliases for the same component, so with this solution you are back to one set of intent filters you are using for everything. PS: Android sucks

Comment: @Nappy no, the point of activity aliases is to allow you to refactor an old class that someone added as a launcher shortcut without breaking their experience, or maintain compatibility with some older, exposed API. Sure it would be more convenient if android rewrote the back stack on our behalf, but they don’t. Intent filters are androids preferred solution for component mutiplexing