# Android do not launch activity when app is running (on IntentFilter match)

Tags: android, android-activity, usb, intentfilter

I am working on USB device connection. Here my Android phone will work on HOST mode.

I Have specified Intent filter in manifest like:

```
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
```

so whenever my device will connect it will show the popup for USB permission and Launch the TestActivity.

But if My app is running and i am in other activity then also it is launching test activity.

Here I want to avoid launch activity again if my app is already running.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have the workaround for this.
here Intent is registered to the activity so activity will launch definitely on hardware connection
`( ie: on receive of this action 
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />)`

> 1. Create activity without setting layout and add finish  on
>      create.if you want to get device detail then you can get from here.

```
onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)getIntent().getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    finish();
}
```

> 2. Manifest file add set theme for your activity (here  TestActivity)

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `BroadcastReceiver` for `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED`

and in `onReceive()` [Use this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30576053/6666677)

Comment: if I insert USB hardware again then it should not ask user permission to use this hardware. Android will remember hardware.