# Android launch mode issue

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

Although I have been searching on Stack Overflow for quite some time, did not find the answer I want so far.

**1. Problem description:**

- I have an Android app with bunch of activities and submitted to
  Google Play. After it's published, I downloaded it, whenever open the
  app, it starts a new task. I need to click the hardware back button
  several times to kill all the tasks. While, after that, whenever I
  launch the app again, everything is fine.
- Another weird thing is
  that there's no problem if I directly install the app on the device
  through adb command (adb install xxxx.apk)

**2. What I did:**

- originally, in the code, I was using the "standard" launch mode for the launch activity. I encountered the problem as described above.
- after I read the official document, I realized that "standard" mode will launch an instance of the activity everytime, so I changed the launch mode to be "singtop", but the problem is still there.

**3. What I do not understand:**

- Why the app keeps creating new task if I install the app from Google Play. Why "Singtop" launch mode does not work in this case?
- why I do not have the problem when install the app directly through adb command, while I get the problem when install app from Google Play. What's the difference.

**4. Source code for reference:**

- build.gradle (Module:app):

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 23
      buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.example.testing.exampletesting"
          minSdkVersion 17
          targetSdkVersion 22
      }

      buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  }
  ```
- AndroidManifest.xml:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.testing.exampletesting"
      android:versionCode="10"
      android:versionName="1.0.1" >

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <activity
          android:name=".LaunchActivity"
          android:launchMode="standard">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity android:name=".DummyAActivity" />

      <activity android:name=".DummyBActivity" />

      <activity android:name=".DummyCActivity" />

  </application>

  </manifest>
  ```

Comment: I don't think this is a launch mode issue. You might be starting same activity a lot of times. Your app's  flow should be aligned in that case.

Comment: You are seeing this nasty Android bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265