# Home button differents behaviour when app lauched from play store or app launcher

Tags: android, android-intent

I noticed that when I launch my app from the play store, navigate in differents views and then I press the home button, the app will not keep its current view when it comes back on foreground.

But the behaviour is different when launched by the standard launcher, the app will keep its view when it comes back on foreground.

Do you know if a parameter in the manifest could regulate this behaviour? (I'm using a Nexus 5x)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This sounds like this nasty Android bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265