# How come sometimes when I press back button, there are more Activities than there should be?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack

I don't know how to phrase this question.

My app has a simple ViewPager and you click on something in one of those page Fragments and it takes you to another Activity. Press the back button and it takes you back to the ViewPager. Press back again and it closes the app.

However, sometimes when I press the back key at the ViewPager, it takes me back to the other Activity again, and then I press back and it takes me to the ViewPager, and so on, until the app finally closes. In other words it's like there are spare, leftover instances of either the ViewPager or the other Activity in the backstack (I think it's called), but I have no idea how or why this is happening.

I also don't know how to reproduce the error, which is even more frustrating. Most of the time it works as expected, but sometimes the leftover instances just show up out of nowhere as I am pressing back.

How can I guarantee better that when I press the back button on the other Activity, it goes back to the ViewPager, and when I press back on the ViewPager, it closes the app?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: //called when I press back button on the phone or the back-arrow on the toolbar
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//and then usually that's all I have, but in one particular Activity, I do override the function:

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (some conditions are met) {
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else {
        //display some error message
    }
}
```

Here is how I launch my Activities:

```
public void launchSomeActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityName.class);
    intent.putExtra( etc etc etc );
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `finish()` when you start new Activities?

Comment: I added some code to the post

Comment: FInish() and super.onBackPress() are same use any one of those method.

Comment: @ramji Is that's what's causing my problem? Calling both of them?

Comment: `onBackPressed()` will call `finish()` under certain conditions, yes

Comment: So do I call super.onBackPressed or finish() or does it not matter which? Is calling both causing my problem?

Comment: Do you by any chance override `onWindowFocusChanged` in any of your activities or fragments? That might sometimes cause an Activity to be created twice if not handled correctly causing you to have to press back button more times than necessary.

Comment: Hmm, no doesn't sound familiar

Comment: Likely you are seeing a nasty long-standing Android bug. If you launch your app for the **first time** from an IDE, or from the installer, when you put the app in the background and launch it **again** from the HOME screen, Android creates **another instance** of your root `Activity`. This would exhibit exactly the behaviour you are reporting. If you launch the app **for the first time** by pressing the app icon from the HOME screen (or list of available apps), the problem does not occur.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283079/re-launch-of-activity-on-home-button-but-only-the-first-time/16447508#16447508

Comment: @DavidWasser !!!!!!!!!!!! That reproduced my issue! Holy crap this is exactly what is happening. I am going to try again with that root code you wrote and report back.

Comment: @DavidWasser Yep, that resolved it. Thank you! If you make that into an answer here, I will accept it.

Comment: Glad I was able to help solve your problem. Please tell me what version of Android you were testing on

Comment: My android version is 6.0.1, model number SM-N910V (Samsung Galaxy Note 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you are seeing a nasty long-standing Android bug. If you launch your app for the first time from an IDE, or from the installer, when you put the app in the background and launch it again from the HOME screen, Android creates another instance of your root Activity. This would exhibit exactly the behaviour you are reporting. If you launch the app for the first time by pressing the app icon from the HOME screen (or list of available apps), the problem does not occur.

See [Re-launch of Activity on Home button, but...only the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283079/re-launch-of-activity-on-home-button-but-only-the-first-time/16447508#16447508)