# Android App lifecycle issues after going to Homescreen and reopening (only after first app start)

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, homescreen, launchmode, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

When downloading and installing my app from the Play Store, I have the following issue:

After I start the app for the first time I get into my LoginActivity (which has intent-filters MAIN and LAUNCHER), I log in and then start my MainActivity, that has a HomeFragment with a green button. On Button press I hide the green button and show an orange button. If I now press the 'Home' Button, the Device goes to the home screen, then animates to a page where there is space for a new app icon and adds the icon of my app, animated (since it was a fresh download). If I now click on the icon to re-open my app, I get back to my MainActivity and HomeFragment, however the UI seems to be the way as if the Fragment was just created (green button is visible, orange is hidden). If I then press the back button, the Screen seems to close, behind it appears my "old state" MainActivity/HomeFragment, but then the UI quickly changes back to the green button, if I then press the back button again, I leave the app as expected. If I kill the app and restart, this issue no longer occurs, instead the the behaviour is as expected (when pressing home button and reopening the app, the UI is exactly how i left it).

This issue does occurs on my Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1. When going through the same steps described above on a Genymotion Virtual device (Galaxy S3, Android 4.4.1 with play services installed) I do not have the issue, the app is behaving correctly.

This issue never occurs, when I deploy from Android Studio.

Any ideas? what the issue could be?
I have added `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to my MainActivity in manifest, without success.

Obviously the is also hard to debug, since it does not occur when I deploy from Android Studio (even if I uninstall the app first), so I have to submit an update to Play Store first to see results of changes.

Comment: nothing? :/ is this question asked/tagged badly?

Comment: Does this occur if you don't launch the app directly after installing (ie: don't open the app directly from the installer, just close the installer after installation and open the app by clicking on the app icon on the home screen)? If so, you are seeing this nasty Android bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265

Comment: I added the `android` tag to your question. That usually helps to get more attention.