# How to restore previous activity after pressed home button and return to the app

Tags: android, android-intent

the flow is like below.

- MainActivity -> Second Activity
- Press home key then device main screen shown.
- Enter to app box and click the application icon.

I expect the second activity should be launched but main activity launched.

is there any way that I control it -?!

Comment: Provide your code.  By default you have to see the last activity

Comment: Have you finished the last activity on `onDestroy` or other methods ?

Comment: Force stop your app and then launch it again from the HOME screen. Go to `SecondActivity`. Press HOME key. launch your app again. Do you now get the `MainActivity` or the `SecondActivity`?

Comment: You may be seeing this nasty Android bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265

Comment: Any luck? Did you figure this out?

Comment: @DavidWasser the link you provided pointed me in the right direction. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Android behaviour when you press the home button is that the current activity is pushed onto the stack, unless you called finish() in your activity. Whenever you open your application it will launch the activity that's on top of your stack.

I'ts based on your system memory. If you don't have enough memory to keep your activity backgrounded then Android will kill your activity and its state to recoup some memory. I'm thinking that perhaps your phone (or emulated device) is running short of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using for that activity, any `android:noHistory="true"` within your App's manifest. Try removing it.

Answer (score -1):

You filtered your main activity by

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

so it should get launched when you click on the icon in your launcher. I think you should handle your pages with fragments to have the behavior you want.

Comment: There is no need for fragments to get this standard, default Android behaviour. Using fragments won't solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean isSentToBackground = false;

public void onResume(){
 if(isSentToBackground) {
  finish();
 }
}

public void onPause(){
 isSentToBackground = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? I have little experience with Android apps, but where does this restore the previous activity?