# Closing previous Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed

I am new to android and trying my level best.

I am having an application with three activities,
1 login page
2. Home page
3. Registration Page

The first activity loaded is  login
when a user gives correct user name and password I am allowing to Home page
Here I am facing a problem, when I click back button I am going to the login screen again it should not happen the application has to close.

while creating intent and loading home activity i am using finish() also

I tried onBackPressed() method but it does not work for me

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
              //      HomeActivity.this.finish();
                      super.onBackPressed();
      }
```

And my manifest file is

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.Example.MyProject">
        <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc"
        android:label="@string/app_name_display"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
       android:manageSpaceActivity=".LoginActivity"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".SyncData" >
    </service>
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
       <activity android:name=".Registration"  />
       </application>

      </manifest>
```

Comment: When you launch `Home` from `Login` do you also call `finish()`? If so, pressing BACK in `Login` should NOT return to `Home`. Add your manifest to your question please

Comment: yes i am calling but after logout also when i press back button it is loading home screen

Comment: That is not standard Android behaviour. You may be seeing this nasty Android bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265 Please force stop your app and then start it again from the HOME screen. Then login and press the BACK button and see if your `HomeActivity` still shows.

Comment: @DavidWasser, you are correct, Thank you for your helpful link

Comment: Sorry about that. A lot of people have been bitten by this bug :-(

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);

startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

**finish()** will destroy your Login activity once you reach to `HomeActivity.java`
and you wont reach to `LoginActivity` again.

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class));
                                finish();

Comment: @A.Nitesh Don't use this in your `onBackPressed`, instead use it when you redirect your user to the `HomeActivity`

Comment: yes When i i am starting new activity i will close old activity buy calling finish()

Comment: in onBackPressed() method i am using just super.onBackPressed();

Comment: Dont overrride onBackpressed() in HomeActivity.java . just delete that code.

Comment: @Sandiskp then how to handle this issue with out backpress

Comment: @A.Nitesh  Once you reach to HomeActivity by above code. What happens when you delete that backpress method and press android backbutton ?

Comment: on back press i need to close the application if that activity is home else normal back functionality

Comment: You are on HomeActivity, Once you press back from home activity , Your application will get closed. If you are on Registration page you will come on home Activity and then back press will close the application.

Comment: @Sandiskp that is the exact scenario i want but its not working like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
 private Boolean exit = false;

   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (exit) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tap again to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            exit = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: In normal cases its works fine,  but in my allocation having some scenarios like, while logout i am asking wheatherhe want to log out (Yes/no) if user clicks yes then logout is processed here when i pressed back agian is is going to home screen

Answer (score 0):

Just Override your onBackPressed on the second Activity and do not call

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

For instance,Override your onBackPressed like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//Do something else here, maybe prompt the user if he needs to exit the app.
finishAffinity();;//If you want to close the application.
}
```

I would add something like this, to be user friendly

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you wish to exit the app?");

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finishAffinity();
            }
        });

        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: If we do like this back press button itself will not work

Comment: its not my requirment

Comment: Nitesh, as I understand from the question, the back is not supposed to work.

Comment: no no, the back button should not lead us to login activity, consider a example like for facebook if we login once, the application will open and while closing the application it will not lead to login page na

Comment: I am not concern about alert messages and their functionallity, here the major problem is onBackPressed i am going to previous activity that should not happen. For ur clear understanding i will tell you one thing.   After Logout when i press back button it is going to launch home activity

Comment: You can use finishAffinity();

Comment: It will close whole application

Comment: Please rephrase the question if you need a valid response.
"I am going to the login screen again it should not happen the application has to close."
This is what you asked, that is what I replied for.

Answer (score 0):

Another user bitten by [this nasty long-standing Android bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283079/re-launch-of-activity-on-home-button-but-only-the-first-time/16447508#16447508).

If I had a dollar for every hour that was spent by software developers trying to figure this out, I wouldn't have to work anymore.

Google: FIX IT!