# Do not close an activity at the top pf stack on pressing home button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-homebutton, launchmode

I have a launcher `ActivityA` (launch mode - singleTask), that opens `ActivityB` on pressing a button. Now, I press the home button and open the application again. I see `ActivityA` but not `ActivityB`. I want the activity which is displayed before pressing the home button to be displayed even after re-opening the application.

Note: When I change the launcher mode for `ActivityA` to `singleTop`, then this problem gets fixed. But I can't use that launcher mode because of some other unrelated reason (I don't want to create another instance of the `ActivityA`).

Comment: did u try keeping activity b's launch mode as SingleTop ?

Comment: Have a look at this to understand how launch modes work::https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: yeah, I have tried to launch activity B with singleTop and it does not help. :(

Comment: You do not need to use `singleTask` to solve your problem. If `ActivityA` is your root `Activity`, Android will not (generally) create another instance of it if it is launched again, it will just bring your existing task to the foreground. You need to back up and try to solve your problem using the standard launch modes. Please explain exactly the scenario where Android creates 2 instances of `ActivityA`.

Comment: You may be seeing this nasty Android bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265 . To check if you are seeing that bug, kill your app (Settings->Apps->YourAp->Force Stop), then start your app by clicking the icon on from the HOME screen and see if the problem has gone away (ie: it shouldn't start 2 instances, even if you have no special launch mode).

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? Can you tell us what you did?