# App does not retain state after initial install from store

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android application.  When it is initially installed from the store it does not save any activities when it is minimized, if the user minimizes the app and touches the icon the app restarts.  It's almost like the developer option "don't keep activities" is selected.  This only happens if it is installed from the store and only happens the first time the application is run.

Is there anything different about the first time the app is run?  Why don't I see this behavior in the emulator?  Is there any way to have the app behave correctly on the first install?

Comment: This is not a _feature_ of Android nor should be the default case, so you will need to provide much more information and debug much more before we can help you. When you tap an icon from the Launcher, you may receive a different Intent, (with the Launcher stuff) but outside of that, there shouldn't be any difference. Without seeing your app/code/etc., it's hard to tell what your project does to have this behavior.

Comment: Maybe this will help you, kind of the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283079/re-launch-of-activity-on-home-button-but-only-the-first-time