# How to close activity from class with context usage?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I created another class where I have function of logout:

```
fun logOut(context: Context) {    
        context.stopService(Intent(context, CheckNewMessages::class.java))
        val intent = Intent(context, LoginScr::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
        context.startActivity(intent)

        (context as Activity).finish()
    }
```

and as you can see I use this line for finishing activity:

```
(context as Activity).finish()
```

But it is still alive and as a result I have two or more same activities at my system. I tried a lot of ways like creating static variable at first activity and using this variable at the second one for closing. But my activity stays alive. I also tried to use lauchmode at manifest and some other ways. Maybe someone knows where I did a mistake?

### UPDATE

Two places from which I call `logOut()`. 1st is interface between RV adapter and fragment:

```
override fun finish() {
        APICallRequests.logOut(context!!)
        activity!!.finishAffinity()
    }
```

and 2nd at `Interceptor` for requests:

```
private fun updateAccessToken(context: Context) {
        val sp = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_STORAGE, 0)
        synchronized(this) {
            val tokensCall = accessTokenApi()
                    .getNewToken(ReqAccessToken(sp.getString("refresh_token", "")!!))
                    .execute()

            if (tokensCall.isSuccessful) {

            } else {
                when (tokensCall.code()) {
                    500 -> {
                        val thread = object : Thread() {
                            override fun run() {
                                Looper.prepare()
                                Toast.makeText(cont, cont.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                Looper.loop()
                            }
                        }
                        thread.start()
                    }

                    401 -> {
                        APICallRequests.logOut(context)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What calls the function `logOut()` and when the function is called, what is passed in as `context`?

Comment: @DavidWasser, in general it can be called as user presses logout btn, and also from interceptor when the user receives some errors also, I pass fragments as context

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. Anyway, you cannot pass a `Fragment` as a `Context` parameter because `Fragment` doesn't extend `Context`. The compiler would flag this as an error so you are obviously not passing a `Fragment` as `context`.

Comment: Please post the code that calls `logOut()`.

Comment: @DavidWasser, I have just updated my question, check it pls :)

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't help. I need to know what `context` is. How is the value of `context` set?

Comment: I pass it from fragment class, at interceptor it passed at constructor from non acitivity class

Comment: But where do you get the `context` from?

Comment: Please also try this: kill your app (force quit from the settings). Now launch your app from the HOME screen. now do whatever you do and see if you still have 2 copies of the `Activity`. If you don't, then you are just experiencing this nasty long-standing Android bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447508/769265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way it works. What happens is this. When you do:

```
context.startActivity(intent)
```

This doesn't start the new `Activity` immediately. It just requests that Android starts the new `Activity` when it gets control back. Then you do this:

```
(context as Activity).finish()
```

This call just finishes the current `Activity`. When you eventually return control to the Android framework, it will launch the new `Activity` as you requested in your call to `startActivity()`.

If you want your app to exit (ie: all activities finished), you can just do:

```
(context as Activity).finishAffinity()
```

This call will finish the current `Activity` and all other activities in the task that belong to the same app.

**NOTE: This only works if all activities in your app share the same affinity, which is the default case.**

Comment: but the current acitivity can be closed via `.finish()` also?

Comment: It isn't necessary because `finishAffinity()` will close all of them, including the current one.

Comment: but if I finish all activities so my app will be closed, not like `System.exit(0)` but I will be moved on home screen? as for what I want I would like to close activity and open another one, for ex close A and move to B, using `finishAffinity()` will allow me to enter B?

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand your problem then. Do you just want to start a new `Activity` and finish the current one?

Answer (score 1):

try to pass Activity instead of Context in inner param `fun logOut(activity: Activity)`, this should help you if you are calling this function from activity. If you calling it from fragment you can use `requareActivity.finish()`

Comment: I tried this code from fragment with activity passing and it didn't help me