# Duplicate onCreate call problem when making lancher app in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter, activity-lifecycle

I used the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER option to make the app start right after the tablet starts up.
I made it to keep my app even when I press the home button
But there is a problem
When the home button is pressed, onCreate of MainActivity is called again.
I want to call onCreate only once because it is connected to the hardware.
Is there a way?

I cannot use android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED due to circumstances

Comment: Your concept of what these `Intent` filters do is whole wrong... as well the your concept of the `Activity` lifecycle. Please have a look at the documentation, which explains all of that in detail.

Comment: Please read the activity lifecycle here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: Please post your manifest in your question. Your question is difficult to understand. specifying `CATEGORY=LAUNCHER` does NOT make your app start on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your activity is a singleTask activity, then this is a 10 year old, known Android bug, happens when you run your application from Android Studio or from Play Store. Should not happen when the app is launched 'normally' by the user. I think there is nothing you can do about it.

[Re-launch of Activity on Home button, but...only the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283079/re-launch-of-activity-on-home-button-but-only-the-first-time/16447508#16447508)